# Rich faces panel menu item rendering same page

Tags: jsf-1.2

1. Rich faces panel menu item.There are 4 menus. Of that 4th menu contains a menu item where  action=”#{Test.t1}”.Managed Bean : Test ///  Property : t1 [getters & setters]. In t1[getter], loads contents of 4th page.

PROBLEM:
 on clicking 4th menu,  4th menu contents loads. Then on clicking 1st or 2nd or 3rd menu again 4th menu’s page renders but not 1st or 2nd or 3rd.

Tried: 
1.  actionListener to menuItems
        where I tried to redirect to some other page on clicking 1st or 2nd or 3rd menu items.
    Code in action listener:        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("test1.faces");
What happened:   Does not redirect. What expected:  Should redirect before action is performed.

Comment: 2. action=”test1” ; faces-config.xml ; <from-outcome>menu-outcome-5[menu1]</from-outcome> ; Does not seem to trigger this outcome instead it[JSF] triggers some other “outcome” say menu-outcome-6 constantly for menu2, menu3,menu4.
What happened:  JSF does not trigger the desired outcome. What expected:  JSF should trigger the desired outcome.<br/><br/>
3. return outcome by invoking a method. public void test() { return “menu-outcome-2”; }
JSF does not trigger the desired outcome.<br/><br/>

Comment: 4. javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() a. returns the different pages test1[rich faces panel menu1],test2[rich faces panel menu2],test3[rich faces panel menu3],test4[rich faces panel menu4]. <br/>
b. Once [rich faces panel menu4] test4 is rendered, the page on clicking any panel menu item[[rich faces panel menu1,2,3] renders test4[rich faces panel menu4].
Peculiar or strange behavior.

Comment: 5. <navigation-case>
 <from-outcome>.....</from-outcome>
 <to-view-id>.......</to-view-id>
 <redirect />
</navigation-case><br/>

and faces-config.xml<br/>
 action=”panel-menu-item-1?faces-redirect=true”<br/>
action=”panel-menu-item-2?faces-redirect=true”<br/>
…….<br/>
Does not  re-direct.<br/>
<br/>

Comment: Sources:
1. Some sites prefers PrettyFaces & PrimeFaces[Even for re-directing concerns]. Should I use these solutions? Whether anything can be done with JSF itself.